# Accelerometer/Gyroscope views doesn't appear

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios9, accelerometer

I paste this code in Xcode, in the ViewController file. But in the Main.StoryBoard, it is empty. I changed the IOS's version but it's not working.
Can someone can explain me why
https://github.com/loldi/iOS/commit/250156689e648b4642d47f91366d57ac4792d79e
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O68O7yUK_9c

Answer (score 1):

You need to add elements in to your view controller in storyBoard manually and connect its outlet and actions.